# Not recognized as operating system on startup

Tags: system-installation

I am new to Ubuntu and just decided to install it in (on my new lenovo thinkpad) in addition to my windows 7 operating system. Now, whenever I reboot the computer, it only runs window 7. I went (in windows) to **Control Pannel ▸ System ▸ Advanced Settings ▸ Startup** and Ubuntu is not even listed as a choice for operating system. I tried installing ubuntu again, but now it wants to partition the already partitioned windows folder.

I can't figure out how to get Ubuntu, which seems to be installed, to run. I saw on another question here that I could be able to edit my mrb settings using EasyBCD but I can not figure out how to choose ubuntu as an operating system. My disk is already partitioned (seen from the attempted second install) so I'm pretty sure it is on the disk. Basically, how can I get ubuntu to run when I can't choose it as an operating system?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: How did you install it? Wubi or directly on linux partition? Did you choose to put GRUB into MBR or partition? When you start LiveCD do you see your linux partition(s)?

Comment: I agree, sounds as if you choose not to install grub into the MBR. See https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RecoveringUbuntuAfterInstallingWindows

Comment: I used wubi from a flash drive. I tried grub for the mbr partition but all I got was a command line with limited instructions.

Comment: I tried running boot repair from the ubuntu from the flash drive, and I don't know if that works, but it kept on giving me a "efi partition not located" and wasn't able to repair anything.

Comment: This might be an EFI related issue. If your computer has EFI based firmware, make sure to boot the Ubuntu installation DVD in EFI mode (in order to have an EFI bootloader installed). Usually the EFI firmware will list the Ubuntu DVD twice when selecting boot device, once with, and once without (U)EFI written in front of it.

Answer (score 3):

1. Boot using a live cd of ubuntu.
2. Open a terminal and run the command

   ```
   sudo fdisk -l
   ```

   It lists the complete partition table of the hard disk. In there, identify which partition you have got your linux installed on. You can identify it using the drive size you had allocated for it and looking at the last column of the output which will be `extended` for all of your linux partitions. The partition will most probably be something like `/dev/sda5` or something. Remember this partition.
3. Create a temporary folder in your home directory (Note: You can make the temporary folder anywhere you want. I’m using the home folder just for the sake of explanation). I’m calling it ‘temp’ for now. So that ‘temp’ folder’s path will be /home/ubuntu/temp.
4. Mount your linux partition there. That is, assuming that you found your linux partition to be `/dev/sda5`, you mount that at the ‘temp’ folder by doing the following command

   ```
   sudo mount /dev/sda5 /home/ubuntu/temp
   ```
5. If you want to check whether you have mounted the correct partition, go to your home folder and open temp. You will be in the `/` directory. In there you will find `home`, in which your home folder’s name will be there. Once you’ve confirmed you have mounted the correct partition, do step 6.
6. You have to install grub by showing the system where to read the data from the hard disk at the beginning. Don’t worry, just run the following command

   ```
   sudo grub-install –root-directory=/home/ubuntu/temp /dev/sda
   ```

   The `/dev/sda` corresponds to your hard disk name. Replace it by whatever the command `sudo fdisk -l` command showed you.
7. You’re done. You may restart your system.

Do refer to this : http://sosaysharis.wordpress.com/2011/06/29/recovering-grub-after-installing-windows-using-ubuntu/ and let me know if it works.